# Using boto, is there a way to create an AMI from a snapshot ID?

Tags: amazon-ec2, python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ami

There's a command in the AWS EC2 API called ec2-register or ec2reg which has an argument -s for snapshot ID. You are able to create an image from a snapshot. I'd like to be able to do this in Python (currently using boto), but it doesn't look like it's built in functionality within boto yet. Is there still a way using boto to create an image from a snapshot id? Also assume, architecture, kernel, and other attributes are available and S3 access if necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, boto does have an AMI registration function. Please look at http://readthedocs.org/docs/boto/en/latest/ref/ec2.html#boto.ec2.connection.EC2Connection.register_image.

You need to register an AMI with every option except for "image_location". Specify your snapshot id when making the block device mapping object for whatever you specified as your "root_device_name".